# Open graph stories Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am new in Facebook App. and I just discovered Open Graph stories. I'm wondering - where should I insert action and object code? What are the steps in approval procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to this topic but found out some stuff (not completely yet!).

Via developer.facebook.com you have your app. You can add objects / actions to the left of the screen. The approval depends on the rights your app requires. Are you using the open graph for web or mobile app? Eventually you'll need to create a screencast (video) of how Facebook works in your app to get approved.